# Why does my brush size widen?

Tags: sculpting

whenever i hover my brush over an rectangle or any other uneven object my brush widens relative to the shape of the object, i tried to reset my brush settings and it did not work.
Help please

Comment: Do you mean the circle of the brush becomes an ellipse? That happens when you have scaled the object and the scale differs for each axis (=non-uniform scale). Blender warns you about this with the message *"Object has non-uniform scale, sculpting may be unpredictable"* in the status bar. To fix it, switch to *Object* mode, and apply the *Scale* (Ctrl+A).